# VBA, FOR LOOP, IF statement , get the value of the previous cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I would like to write a VBA script that goes down in a column for example from K2 till the last cell in column K (I want it dynamic), and it checks every cell and if a cell is 0 then that cell should get the value of the previous cell.

I started  this way. I am not sure this is the correct way:

```
Sub getpreviouscellvalue()

For Each Cell In Range("K2:K26")
    If Cell.Value = 0 Then
        
        Cell.Value = ?
        
        Exit For
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Or  maybe it should be like this code (python):

```
list= [1,2,3,0,4,5]
for i in list;
a = list.index(i)
if i== 0;
list[a]=list[a-1]
Print(list)
```

I hope it's understandable. If not feel free to write me and I can explain it more.

Comment: Please show us where you are: we need the code which you assembled yourself.

Comment: I edited my post with the codes. Thank you ZygD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you intend:

```
Sub getpreviousvalue()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("K2:K26")
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            cell.Value = cell.Offset(-1).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much ZygD. That is exactly what I was intent to do. You are the best.
May I also ask you how the code would be if instead of a fixed range like now Range("K2:K26"),  it would be a dynamic range that always change. For example sometimes its K30 sometimes is 40 etc. so the program should stop when it  reaches the last row of data.   Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: It's possible, but it's best to ask a separate question for this.